# Redirect URL with Argument in urls.py in Django 1.6.5

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I recently switched from PHP to Django. My old site in PHP had Disqus integrated, when I migrated to new site, my blog urls changed from ***/blog/<year>/<month>/<slug>*** to ***/blog/<slug>***

All new comments are automatically taking the new url, but there are a lot of old links that are still in the form of ***<year>/<month>/<slug>***

Now what I want it to redirect all ***/blog/<year>/<month>/<slug>*** to ***/blog/<slug>***

I tried the following:

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('view_blog_post'))),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', 'blog.views.view_post', name='view_blog_post'),
```

This gives me the following errors:

```
view_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'year'
```

which seems obvious because my view only takes slug as an argument. I don't want to write another view to incorporate this change because it is temporary.

Please help me find a solution on this.

Regards.

Comment: What is your view function like? Try passing `year, month, slug` to it in the function signature, instead of just `slug`. Tell me if that works?

Comment: this is my function definition: `def view_post(request, slug, year=None, month=None):`

Comment: while now I get a different error: `Reverse for 'blog.views.view_post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<slug>[^\\.]+)']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `view_blog_post` pattern requires a slug, so you can't just do `reverse_lazy('view_blog_post')` because it does not use the slug.

Instead, you can use the [`pattern_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.pattern_name) argument, then Django will use the args and kwargs to reverse the url.

You also want to make the year and month [non capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) using `?:`, because you do not want to use these to reverse the url.

```
url(r'^(?:\d{4})/(?:\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='view_blog_post', permanent=True)),
```

The default of [`permanent`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.permanent) is switching to `False` in Django 1.9, so it's good to set it explicitly to prevent it from changing accidentally when you upgrade.

Comment: now that works perfectly, just one thing, you forgot it place a "\" infront of the first d{4}, if you correct that, I shall mark it as answer. Cheers.